# Matplotlib split animated line

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting a line with matplotlib, and I use an animation. Let's say there is

```
__line_1, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2, label="1")
```

My Animation is done with a FuncAnimation. Now I do have a problem. I am plotting Values of Angles in a Range from 0 to 360. But the input values can be larger. If they are larger, I use modulo to bring them down to my range. Bad thing is:
When I come across a line with angle values like (358, 359, 360, 361), the values on my plot are (358, 359, 0, 1). This works as intended, but the plotted line has a connection from my 359 to 0 value. Is there a way to suppress this? So let's say, draw a line from 357, 358. 359, and then continue at the bottom of my plot at 0, 1, 2, and not draw this vertical connection line between 359 and 0?

EDIT:

I found a workaround for this problem: I do have enough values that are close enough to each other, so i can use point markers instead of a full line. But this is only a small solution for the problem, if your values are not as close to each other as mine are, you will only have random points in your plot. Here is what I did:

```
__line_1, = ax.plot([], [],'.', lw=2, label="1")
```

EDIT2:

I am now using simple plotting instead of animations. Can anybody pls tell me how you can split a line if you do not want it to connect from the bottom to the top of your plot or vice versa?

Comment: does nobody have any idea?